# SSL Certificate error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] when using aws client in windows 10

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, proxy, ssl-certificate, zscaler

Recently I am gettin an error when, for instance, listing data from Amazon S3:

```
aws s3 ls

SSL validation failed for https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)
```

I have noticed that the company I work for has added a ZScaler Client Connector. It seems that this client is causing the error. I wonder if someone could give a hint about how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 6):

Upps It seems that I found the solution myself.

Check this site:

https://www.shellhacks.com/aws-cli-ssl-validation-failed-solved/

I downloaded ZScaler certificate and then pointed from config:

```
$ cat ~/aws/.config
[default]
ca_bundle = /data/ca-certs/whatevername.pem
```

I was getting crazy, I hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 5):

Solved it this way:

1. Locate certifi bundle (cacert.pem) location `python -m certifi`
2. `export AWS_CA_BUNDLE="[full path to cacert.pem]"` from step 1
3. verify

Comment: This solution fixed my issue. thanks